# how to create a camera action common for all android devices

Tags: java, android, upload, camera

in my app i want use the camera for capturing image and send to a server.

When the user opens the Camera part of my app, i want to show him the default camera of the device he is using. At present following is the two line code which i am using to capture image

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
 startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_RECEIPT);
```

When i run this code in a HTC device, after capturing the image it showed a preview of the image with a **done and retake** button. When i click **done** it moves to the previous activity.

when i use the code in a moto device, after capturing the image it showed a preview of the image with a **insert, retake and cancel**. When i click **done** it moves to the previous activity.

Like this it will be differing for all devices. So when i click the **done or insert or any other button positive button** of any devices i want to start the uploading process.

How to proceed this please help me....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use below code to solve your problem...

```
protected void startCameraActivity() 

{

    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE );
        intent.putExtra( MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri );

        startActivityForResult( intent, 0 );
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) 
    {   
        switch( resultCode )
        {
            case 0:
                break;

            case -1:
                onPhotoTaken();
                break;
        }
    }

    protected void onPhotoTaken()
    {

        ///write code here what you want to done after capture the image using device camera
    }

    @Override 
    protected void onRestoreInstanceState( Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        if( savedInstanceState.getBoolean( add_project1.PHOTO_TAKEN ) ) 
        {
            onPhotoTaken();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState( Bundle outState ) 
    {
        outState.putBoolean( add_project1.PHOTO_TAKEN, _taken );
    }
```

Comment: can you give me complete code ? or I post my problem here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13599201/get-error-when-capture-image/13599823#13599823

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if the question is only about how to upload the image after the capture.. but if it is just it, I'll provide you a solution to handle it after you get back from the capture intent to your activity.

You can specify a path to save your image when you start the capture intent:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.jpg");
outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_RECEIPT);
```

You can then handle the upload in your onActivityResult:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == TAKE_RECEIPT) {
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {             
                // user took a picture, upload it
                // outputFileUri contains the uri to your file
                // you should delete it when the upload completes

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //user canceled - do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the problem Arrives when we run this code on the Google nexus 1 device 
as it captures the images then when we click the done button exception arises..that is null pointer in Uri SelectedImage = data.getData();