# Capture and upload photo to php server from Android

Tags: php, android, android-camera, image-uploading, image-capture

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem with uploading captured image in android camera](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149935/problem-with-uploading-captured-image-in-android-camera)

In my android application I want to capture an image and upload it to the php server... how can i proceed?

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Maybe you could send the captured image through Webservice to your PHP server.

Comment: Searched for ages? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6149935/problem-with-uploading-captured-image-in-android-camera

Answer (score 1):

Please view [this link](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/) for general question guidelines.

Try using [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+take+picture) or [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html) for picture capture.

And try [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=android+php+upload+picture) for the picture upload.

Also, I want to point out that you have two separate questions. One is "How do I take a picture?" and the other is "How do I upload a picture to a PHP server?" If you searched one question at a time, wither proper search terms, then you would've found what I gave you above.

And it is rather impolite to ask for full code. This site is to help YOU write the code, not for you to get the code for free.