# Get Error when capture image

Tags: android, android-intent, android-camera

I want to capture image using camera and want image path.

I try following code but I get Error. (I follow this link [Get Path of image from ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE Intent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4184951/get-path-of-image-from-action-image-capture-intent))

Here is my code.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity  extends Activity {
 private static final int CAMERA_REQUEST = 1888; 
    private ImageView imageView;
    private Uri mCapturedImageURI;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        this.imageView = (ImageView)this.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        Button photoButton = (Button) this.findViewById(R.id.button1);
        photoButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {



            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {


                 String fileName = "temp.jpg";  
                 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
                 values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, fileName);  
                 mCapturedImageURI = getContentResolver().insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, values);  

                 Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);  
                 intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, mCapturedImageURI);  
                 startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST);
            }
        });
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {  
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {  

             String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA}; 
             Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection, null, null, null); 
             int column_index_data = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA); 
             cursor.moveToFirst(); 
             String capturedImageFilePath = cursor.getString(column_index_data);

             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), capturedImageFilePath.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }  
    } 
}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="photo" >
    </Button>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" >
    </ImageView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera"></uses-feature>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.example.cameraupload/com.example.cameraupload.MainActivity}: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1888, result=-1, data=null} to activity {com.example.cameraupload/com.example.cameraupload.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: what's the error? Any logCat exceptions?

Comment: @SamSPICA : I upload code with error

Comment: You'll find the exact file and line number after the NullPointerException where the Exception actually occured. As the exception suggests, the object being pointed at is null. Look at that object, and see if it is declared correctly.

Comment: @SamSPICA : All are correct . I think you try code , you get better idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got Ans.

photoButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

```
        public void onClick(View v) {

           File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test1.jpg");
            Uri outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
            Intent intent = new Intent(android.provider.MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
            startActivityForResult(intent, 0);

        }
    });



protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        Log.i("MakeMachine", "requestCode:"+requestCode + ",resultCode: " + resultCode);

                        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test1.jpg");
                        if(file.exists()){
                            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                            options.inSampleSize = 4;
                            picFileName=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/test.jpg";
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), picFileName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picFileName, options);
                            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                            //imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if (resultCode != RESULT_CANCELED) {
    if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST) {

     String[] projection = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
      Cursor cursor = managedQuery(mCapturedImageURI, projection,                   null, null, null);
                int column_index_data = cursor
                        .getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
                cursor.moveToFirst();
                String capturedImageFilePath = cursor
                        .getString(column_index_data);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        capturedImageFilePath.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();

            }
        }
```

you try this one i think they will help you..

Comment: which device you have testing? @NiravRanpara

Comment: See I post Working ans of my question